# javascript array object value contains another array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array like this

```
"chapters":[
            {
                "_id": "5422c6ba0f6303ba22720e14",
                "chapter_name": "Morbi imperdiet libero sed.",
                "sub_title": "Nam id elit tincidunt amet.",
                 "mystatus": "noidea"   

            },
            {
                "_id": "5422bd0d5cb79ae6205b2f6a",
                "chapter_name": "Donec id accumsan volutpat.",
                "sub_title": "Cras volutpat velit nullam.",
                 "mystatus": "noidea"

            },
            {
                "_id": "5423ea5f17c83ad41da1765e",
                "chapter_name": "Donec id accumsan volutpat.",
                "sub_title": "Cras volutpat velit nullam.",
                 "mystatus": "noidea"

            }

        ],
```

And I have another one

```
"currentstat": [
        "5423ea5f17c83ad41da1765e",
        "5422c6ba0f6303ba22720e14",
        "5422bd0d5cb79ae6205b2f6a"
    ],
```

I want to check any of `currentstat` array value contains in `chapters._id`.

And I tried like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
  var attenId = currentstat.toString();
  if (attenId.indexOf(chapters[i]._id) != -1) {
  }
}
```

I could not get the result without

> var attenId = currentstat.toString();

*one more thing I need on this.*

I need to assign these `status` array value to  corresponding `chapters` array as per `currentstat` array value.

```
status: [ 'passed', 'passed', 'attending']
```

the whole code is like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
  var attenId = currentstat.toString();
  if (attenId.indexOf(chapters[i]._id) != -1) {
    allChapters[i].mystatus = (status[i]) ? status[i] : 0;
  }
}
```

but the value does not assign to corresponding `_id` Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
var currentstat = ["1","2","3"];
var chapters = [{_id:"2"}, {_id:"4"}, {_id:"6"}];

var objects = chapters.filter(function(chapter) {
    return ~currentstat.indexOf(chapter._id);
});
```

Just replace those arrays with your data and `objects` will contain the objects that has same id (in this particular example it is `[{_id:"2"}]`.

Answer (score 1):

The crudest of methods is 2 for loops one inside the other:

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentstat.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < chapters.length; j++) {
        if (currentstat[i] === chapters[j]._id){
            alert('found it at: ' + i + ' ' + currentstat[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3chwwh9/)

a bit less crude method would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
    if (currentstat.indexOf(chapters[i]._id) >= 0) {
        alert('found ' + currentstat[i] + ' at index ' + i);
    }
}
```

[fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/y3chwwh9/2/)

Comment: Using `indexOf` would probably be better than iterating on each iteration.

Comment: However, you would need to apply it on `chapters` not on `currentstat`…

Comment: Just submitted an edit that does that and makes sure to let falsy index 0 pass evaluation.